# Retornar diferença entre maior e menor valor de array em Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

Estou tentando fazer um código em assembly com arq. x86 usando o NASM.

Neste código eu devo retornar a diferença entre o maior valor e menor valor de um array, conforme abaixo.

Entretanto, ao rodar está retornando 14 para o exemplo abaixo sendo que o correto seria 18 (20-2). Poderiam me ajudar a encontrar meu erro? Muitíssimo grato desde já.

```
section .data
    array: DB 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20
    size EQU $-array

section .text

global _start
_start:

    mov eax,[array]
    mov ebx,[array]

    xor ecx,ecx
    mov edx,size

jmp compara

maior:
    mov eax,[array+ecx]
    jmp volta_maior

menor:
    mov ebx,[array+ecx]
    jmp volta_menor

compara:
    cmp ecx,edx
    jnle fim
    cmp [array+ecx],eax
    jge maior
volta_maior:
    cmp [array+ecx],ebx
    jle menor
volta_menor:
    inc ecx
    jmp compara

fim:

    sub eax,ebx
    mov ebx,eax
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem 2 problemas com o programa:

*1)* Como o array é formado por *bytes,* todas as operações com os dados (carga, comparações, etc.) devem ser feitas com registradores de 8 bits e não 32. Exemplo:

```
_start:

    mov al,[array]      ; carrega o registrador al (8 bits) com o valor [array]
    mov bl,[array]      ; carrega o registrador bl (8 bits) com o valor [array]
    ...
```

*2)* O final do *looping* deve ocorrer quando `ecx` for igual a (ou maior que) `edx`:

```
compara:
    cmp ecx,edx
    jge fim                 ; Executa até que ecx >= edx
    cmp [array+ecx],eax
    jge maior
```

O programa modificado (com o *looping* corrigido e registradores trocados para os de 8 bits) fica assim:

```
section .data
    array: DB 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20
    size EQU $-array

section .text

global _start
_start:

    mov al,[array]
    mov bl,[array]

    xor ecx,ecx
    mov edx,size

    jmp compara

maior:
    mov al,[array+ecx]
    jmp volta_maior

menor:
    mov bl,[array+ecx]
    jmp volta_menor

compara:
    cmp ecx,edx
    jge fim
    cmp [array+ecx],al
    jge maior

volta_maior:
    cmp [array+ecx],bl
    jle menor

volta_menor:
    inc ecx
    jmp compara

fim:
    sub al,bl
    movzx ebx,al
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80
```

Após a execução:

```
~/$ ./a.out
~/$ echo $?
18
~/$
```

Comment: Eu tava fazendo online por não ter o nasm ou outro assembler, e nada de conseguir, acho que o problema é o online que tem problema com o IO.

Comment: Sim, o programa não tem IO e o compilador online precisa mostrar o resultado através do código de retorno para o S.O. No [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-assembler-nasm-online) é possível compilar e ver esse código de retorno :)

Comment: Não conhecia esse, legal...

Comment: P.S.: eu uso o https://tio.run/#assembly-nasm para compilar. Ele é bem interessante e também permite ver o retorno!

Comment: @Gomiero no teu código na função "compara" ele faz "cmp [array+ecx],al" e caso seja maior ou igual ele vai para "maior" e caso contrário ele continua e faz "cmp [array+ecx],bl", é isso? Obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: @LéoEduardoSilva Sim, é o mesmo código da pergunta. Eu só troquei os registradores `eax` e `ebx` por `al` e `bl`.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado, @Gomiero. Obrigado também pela explicação!